Custom field value as toEmail with CraftCMS Contact Form
Is it possible to set a recipients email address via a custom field with the Contact Form plugin?
I have tried using
{% set recipient = entry.recipientEmail %}
And then hashing the recipient variable like:
<input type="hidden" name="toEmail" value="{{ recipient|hash }}">

But it doesn't work.

As described in the documentation for Contact Form, in addition to the hidden name="toEmail" input in your form, you'll need to add some logic to your config/contact-form.php file:
<?php

// Contact Form config settings
$config = [
    ...
];

// Logic for adding the dynamic email recipient
$request = Craft::$app->request;

if (
    !$request->getIsConsoleRequest() &&
    ($toEmail = $request->getValidatedBodyParam('toEmail')) !== null
) {
    $config['toEmail'] = $toEmail;
}

return $config;


I don't think this addresses the part about the email coming from the entry field?

No, because I didn't consider that part a problem – as long as the recipient variable contains an email address and you've added the necessary code to your config/contact-form.php as per the above, the way you've set this up should work. If it doesn't, you'll have to be more specific – do you get any error messages? What kind of field is entry. recipientEmail?

No specific error. The email just arrives at the fallback in the CP. I've tried it as a text field and a email field.

Hard to say what's wrong, then. The recipient variable value should just be a (hashed) string with an email address, so the way you're doing it should work. Maybe try adding a \Craft::dd($toEmail); inside the if statement in the config file to confirm that the recipient email address does end up in the Contact Form config.
